# ActiveRecord Rails convert created_at timestamp to required timezone in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, timezone, timestamp

**Situation**:

I am working on a Rails application with **UTC** as the application timezone so data for any user coming from any zone will be saved in UTC format in database.

Lets suppose one of the user from Central Time (US & Canada) (difference of 5 hours from UTC) signups on my website on ***28th July 2014 6:45 pm***. Thus the created_at for the user in database will be ***Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:45:00 UTC +00:00***. Now the same user uploads a photo in Photo model the same day at ***7:30 pm***. So value of created_at in Photo records for the user will be ***Tue, 29 Jul 2014 00:30:30 UTC +00:00***.

Thus storing values in UTC brings a difference of **1 day** between the user created_at and Photo stored for the user though the user practically uploaded the photo on the same day as signed up on the website.

**Requirement**:

I want to find all the photos uploaded by the user created on the same day as the user created. So I implemented the query -

**Expected Result
=> 1**

```
u = User.first
u.created_at
=> Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:45:00 UTC +00:00

u.photos.where('Date(created_at) = ?', u.created_at).count
=> 0 {Failed - Because the db compares the time in UTC}
```

After lot of search and research I came to know about setting Time.zone to the user time zone.

```
u = User.first
Time.zone = u.time_zone
=> Central Time (US & Canada)

u = User.first
u.created_at
=> Mon, 28 Jul 2014 18:45:49 CDT -05:00 {Correct Time as per my requirements}

Photo.where('user_id = ? and Date(created_at) = ?', u.id, u.created_at).count
=> 0 {Failed}
```

But When I tried to find created_at of photo record uploaded by the user  it return the correct timestamp -

```
u.photos.first.created_at
=> Sun, 28 Jul 2014 19:30:00 CDT -05:00
```

*Thus setting Time.zone only enables Ruby to return time in the specified time zone but Rails Active Record continues to compare time in UTC.*

Can anyone please suggest is there any way of using Active Record queries by changing the timestamp from utc to user time_zone.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old post, but in the event that others read this post I found help using the `local_time` gem, which renders the saved date into the users timezone: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time

Otherwise I think this tutorial may be what you need if you absolutely must change the timezone in the DB: https://gorails.com/episodes/auto-detect-user-time-zones-in-rails